# Python-Trying to make a file witho os in directory, no errors but the file won't appear

Tags: python, python-os

I want to create a txt file in appdata/roaming/Helloworld with os method. The file is my_file.txt and when I launch the programm, there is no error and python says that the file and the folder exists (`os.path.exists(file_path)` returns True) but when I go to my %AppData% folder (AppData/roaming), there is no folder named Helloworld.

here is the code:

```
directory = os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'), 'Helloworld')
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
file_path = os.path.join(directory, 'my_file.txt')
if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write('Hello World!')
```

I tryed `os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)` and it didn't work better.

Comment: What is `directory`? I'm not sure why you assume it's in `AppData`

Comment: thank I forget to precise in this post but I think it's AppData/roaming. I edited my post

Comment: try adding some print statements or check out [pdb - The Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) to debug small programs `python3 -m pdb myscript.py` .. use `b` to set a breakpoint (so you can inspect your program there), `c` to run up to that point (continue), and `?` to explore commands .. this will allow you to inspect the live state of your program wherever you breakpoint or continue to

Comment: "Think" is not good enough. If the program finishes without error, it wrote your file _somewhere_. You need to debug it to find out _where_. You don't need a debugger, just throw `print` calls in until you're satisfied

Comment: I made it with `print(directory)` and I obtained a path that I0 copied and paste to files explorer and the path doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you configured Explorer to allow you to see hidden files and folders? `AppData` is usually hidden, so Explorer likely won't show you it with default settings.

Comment: yes I did it but i just wrote %AppData% in the explorer

Comment: Your code looks fine. I would download the sysinternal process monitor this should tell you exactly what's going on. sysinternals is a suite of tools written by Mark Russinovich, the CTO of Microsoft Azure; it's an amazing resource for working out what's happening under the hood in Windows. Process monitor will list all the system operations called by your script, like CreateFile CloseFile etc.; this should let you work out what's going wrong.